# How do I find a function g that yields a specific answer when composed with f?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Let
$f(x)=\frac x{x-2}$
. Find a function $y=g(x)$ so that $(f\circ g)(x)=4x$.

The solution is $g(x)=\frac{8x}{4x-1}$, but I don't know how to arrive at this answer.  Please help me to find the steps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. We know that $f(x)=\frac{x}{x-2}$

we also know that if we replace the variable x in f(x) with g(x) (let's call it "G" for simplicity) we must get 4x as a result. Let's write that down:
$$\frac{G}{G-2}=4x$$
$$G=4x(G-2)$$
$$G=4xG-8x$$
$$G-4xG=-8x$$
$$G(1-4x)=-8x$$
$$G=\frac{-8x}{(1-4x)}$$
$$G=\frac{8x}{4x-1}$$

Answer (score 8):

If $g(x)=y$ then
$$4x=f(g(x))=f(y)=\frac{y}{y-2}$$
hence $4xy-8x=y$, from which you get
$$y=\frac{8x}{4x-1}$$

Therefore $g(x)=y=\frac{8x}{4x-1}$.

Comment: Can show how $4xy-8x=y$ leads to $y=\frac{8x}{4x-1}$?  I'm stuck there.

Comment: @error Solve for $y$. "Move" all the $y$ on a side, and everything else on the other. So $4xy-8x=y$ becomes (moving $y$ to the left) $4xy-y=8x$. Then factorize $y(4x-1)=8x$ and then divide both terms. This is the standard procedure in linear equations in one variable!

Comment: I don't see why adding $y$ makes it any easier. It looks more complicated and less intuitive to me.

Comment: @Mehrdad it does not make any difference, in theory. But, especially for beginners, $y$ looks more like a "number" while $g(x)$ is less transparent as it reminds of a function (although, for fixed $x$, it is of course a number).

Answer (score 6):

Just write $(f\circ g)(x)$, which is $$\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-2}.$$ Now solve the equation $$\dfrac{g(x)}{g(x)-2}=4x$$ with respect to the variable $g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac { x }{ x-2 } ,y=g(x),(f\circ g)(x)=4x\\ \left( f\circ g \right) (x)=f\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) =\frac { g\left( x \right) }{ g\left( x \right)-2 } =4x\Rightarrow \quad g\left( x \right)=4xg\left( x \right)-8x\Rightarrow g\left( x \right)\left( 4x-1 \right) =8x\\ \Rightarrow g\left( x \right)=\frac { 8x }{ 4x-1 } \\ $$

Comment: I'm getting `[Math Processing Error]` on this answer.

Comment: can you show a reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all MathJax tells me.